# MAMP php 5.6.2 file_get_contents not working (timeout)

Tags: php, mamp

I have searched and cannot find a reason why this isn't working. I have tried executing from command line as well as apache and it does not work.

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://google.com");
?>
```

I have a simple php script as shown above that simply makes a request to google and outputs the contents.

Error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://google.com): failed to open stream: Operation timed out in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/p.php on line 2
```

PHP version:
   PHP 5.6.2 (cli) (built: Oct 20 2014 16:21:27)

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

The odd part is if I use /usr/bin/php it works fine. (Built in apple version)

Here is the wireshark capture:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7jdg494fmud22i/packet_capture_php_network.pcapng?dl=0

Comment: Do you have any firewall activated?

Comment: I have tried disabling the firewall and it still happens. The really odd part is that I tried it on another network and it worked fine. I just don't understand how /usr/bin/php works on both networks; but MAMP php does not work on this network.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a CURL alternative:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Curl doesn't work either. I posted a simple example just for clarity.

Comment: Its a network related problem then. Do you know how to trace packets out and in of your network?

Comment: I don't know how to trace packets. Can you post an answer on how to do this? I just find it very odd that apple shipped php works fine; but MAMP php doesn't

Comment: Its actually not that complex, and quite interesting, just download https://www.wireshark.org/download.html and look for a video in youtube on how to trace http related packets

Comment: I have added the wireshark capture. It looks like there is a lot of retransmission attempts

Answer (score 0):

Your apache server might have restrictions on it. Check out this [post](http://kb.oboxthemes.com/articles/warning-file_get_contents-function-file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream-error-in-updater/) which details the fix. Should just be a config change in your `php.ini` file (make sure you change the MAMP PHP's `php.ini` file).

Comment: As stated in my post `allow_url_fopen = On`